# Alternative to returning boolean within subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using angular and trying to return within a subscription which I know isn't allowed. I am wondering though what other solution is available?

I have a hasChildren method which subscribes to a checkChildren method (this is where the API call is). This hasChildren method is then called in another class and expects a boolean. Can anyone advise on the alternative way of doing things?

```js
export class Services {

    constructor(
        protected httpClient: HttpClient,
        protected backendService: BackendService
    ) { }


    serviceCodeAppend: string;
    childrenBool: boolean;

    hasChildren(serviceCode: string): boolean{
        console.log('in hasChildren');
        this.checkChildren(serviceCode).subscribe((codes) => {
            console.log(codes)
            if (codes.length == 0) {
                this.childrenBool = false;
            } else {
                this.childrenBool = true;
            }
            return this.childrenBool;
        });
    }

    checkChildren(serviceCode: string): Observable<any> {
        console.log('function checkChildren called');
        this.serviceCodeAppend = serviceCode + "_";
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.backendService.url}/table_name?service=like.${this.serviceCodeAppend}`).pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                this.backendService.handleError(error);
                return of({});
            })
        ).pipe(shareReplay(1));
    }

}
```

I need the boolean in this line of code in another class:

```
if (this.service.hasChildren(selectedSectorCode)) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: you need to use `rxjs/operatoes` for this

Comment: why don't you return an observable from the service and subscribe in the class that needs the boolean?

Comment: You can use `forkJoin()` rxjs in pipe to get combination results of two subscription of observable.

Comment: Think of observables as a value that you can't have now because it needs an asynchronous call to get it, but that you will get later. You can't get a boolean from this method, since you need an asynchronous call to know the boolean value. So what can you return? An Observable<boolean>. How do you transform the Observable<any> returned by checkChildren into an Observable<boolean>? By using the map operator. And please, stop using `any`.

Comment: How would the map operator work in this situation

Comment: If you could share the class that needs the boolean would be awesome. I've run into similar issues before.

Comment: @Spiderman question editted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix for this would be:

In your service class, I would return an observable (`Observable<boolean>`) and use map to format the data to return a boolean: `codes.length == 0` is `true` or `false` no need for if statement.

```
     hasChildren(serviceCode: string): Observable<boolean>{
        return this.checkChildren(serviceCode).pipe(map((codes) => {
            console.log(codes)
            return codes.length == 0;
        }));
    }
```

Don't forget to import `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

In the other class I would:

```
this.service.hasChildren(selectedSectorCode).subscribe((check) => {
     if (check)) {
        // do something
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As Gauran said you could use forkJoin.
From learn rxjs

> Why use forkJoin? This operator is best used when you have a group of
>   observables and only care about the final emitted value of each. One
>   common use case for this is if you wish to issue multiple requests on
>   page load (or some other event) and only want to take action when a
>   response has been received for all. In this way it is similar to how
>   you might use Promise.all.

Example can be founf at https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: My issue isn't numerous observables, its just figuring out how to return a boolean from an API call dataset

Comment: With forkjoin you basically synchronize the 2 observables. That would give you the outcome you need. Honestly though, i think using map as @spiderman suggested in his answer is a better approach.